# WS Security 1.2 in SOAP web services Delphi XE8 for sign body

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, token, ws-security

I have read that there is no way to create a message with ws-security from httprio, only modifying the xml that is generated, in the beforeexecute, overwriting the stream content.
But I want to know how sign the body section from that xml.

In JBoss this is the example (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/WS-Security.html) but I don't find classes or methods in Delphi for do it.

The wsdl definition include a wsp section not readed when imported the wsdl definition

```xml
<wsp:Policy xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy" wsu:Id="SecurityServiceSignThenEncryptPolicy">
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
      <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:InitiatorToken>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                <wsp:Policy>
                  <sp:WssX509V1Token11/>
                </wsp:Policy>
              </sp:X509Token>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:InitiatorToken>
          <sp:RecipientToken>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                <wsp:Policy>
                  <sp:WssX509V1Token11/>
                </wsp:Policy>
              </sp:X509Token>
           </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:RecipientToken>
          <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
          <sp:Layout>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:Lax/>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:Layout>
          <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
          <sp:EncryptSignature/>
          <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
          <sp:SignBeforeEncrypting/>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
      <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <sp:Body/>
      </sp:SignedParts>
      <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <sp:Body/>
      </sp:EncryptedParts>
      <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:Wss10>
    </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Then I need rewrite the xml before request with a token and the body encrypted with that token.

I need encrypt the body with a token, that is how jboss do it.
No user or password. Only encrypt the message.

My original xml normal for call webservice look as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <shawAny xmlns="http://showany.com/webservices">
           <Value xmlns="">1360814</nroCertificado>
           <autenticacion xmlns="">                                       <signWSAA>EISgwe7vyrAtvpe/uBy1Vj9IyYRGjjZfY4isNTLYDhl33BeqPWHjJ5NXU5+UMBSxjAO84bCydJJmCiDlATZq725EThMppowyO2CcAYBET8zBdqlXqaVMT12OHFnSH5QHc5aG4SkrgubPXqCeJO5Lcb/T6irySorBaYG647K33/8=</signWSAA>
          <CN>dnra</CN>    <ticketWSAA>CjxhdXRoPgoJPGlkIHVuaXF1ZV9pZD0iNzQwMDE0NjUyIiBzcmM9IkM9UFksIE89ZG5hLCBPVT1zb2ZpYSwgQ049d3NhYXRlc3QiIGdlbl90aW1lPSIyMDIwLTA3LTIwVDEwOjI5OjI3LjYzMi0wNDowMCIgZXhwX3RpbWU9IjIwMjAtMDctMjFUMTA6Mjk6MjcuNjMyLTA0OjAwIi8+Cgk8b3BlcmF0aW9uIHZhbHVlPSJncmFudGVkIiB0eXBlPSJsb2dpbiI+CgkJPGxvZ2luIHVpZD0iQz1QWSwgTz1ETlJBLCBPVT1USSwgQ049ZG5yYSIgc2VydmljZT0ic2VydmljaW9jZXJuYWMiIGF1dGhtZXRob2Q9ImNtcyI+CgkJPC9sb2dpbj4KCTwvb3BlcmF0aW9uPgo8L2F1dGg+Cg==</ticketWSAA>
         </autenticacion>
      </showAny>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope
```

and then ws-security must look as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <wsse:Security xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
 <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
               EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
               ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509"
               wsu:Id="x509cert00">CjxhdXRoPgoJPGlkIHVuaXF1ZV9pZD0iMTYwMTE4MTMwIiBzcmM9IkM9UFksIE89ZG5hLCBPVT1zb2ZpYSwgQ049d3NhYXRlc3QiIGdlbl90aW1lPSIyMDIwLTA3LTIwVDE1OjUzOjMyLjAxMC0wNDowMCIgZXhwX3RpbWU9IjIwMjAtMDctMjFUMTU6NTM6MzIuMDEwLTA0OjAwIi8+Cgk8b3BlcmF0aW9uIHZhbHVlPSJncmFudGVkIiB0eXBlPSJsb2dpbiI+CgkJPGxvZ2luIHVpZD0iQz1QWSwgTz1ETlJBLCBPVT1USSwgQ049ZG5yYSIgc2VydmljZT0ic2VydmljaW9jZXJuYWMiIGF1dGhtZXRob2Q9ImNtcyI+CgkJPC9sb2dpbj4KCTwvb3BlcmF0aW9uPgo8L2F1dGg+Cg==
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
 <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse SOAP-ENV"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#TheBody"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>VhsSnaEAFsY0OYegKQh99v9csXg=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>axkNSVJdFcJWvd9H2TFYC5AvKLs8c3aMxeXKr0ZrQFWUp7fGivPtAAbQAlO2Wju14sy+TM1POyRd8blkJLLYVcFokrRj7X2SshbKasIosH9aWVoMdl8cL7G1SmUBguxekuI4N++yAAHJZotBka575Eaj3bNlSMNTZL5K2hqTFxal/oIExwDMNAmtCpiEapHgaW7mXgqibttNKhxrGmAGidBnHVGgqMcbM3l6aWhD8F6L4IK1PuB1LQoW/n8wkeO2+PrUzIqQ4LY5+Bx69OZjNHcuiC7HdwMNH9+aMipa7b3Q3DZ0+Qi4k/DWbT3kxterYnOWk6XULifV0F2pH3lg4Q==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><wsse:SecurityTokenReference><wsse:Reference URI="#x509cert00" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="TheBody">
 <getVersion xmlns="http://msgsec.wssecfvt.ws.ibm.com"/>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</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write and append the XML for the security header manually.
The Delphi SOAP implementation has TSOAPHeader objects for that.

Example:

```
type
  TMySoapHeader = class(TSOAPHeader)
  private
    FSomeData: string;
  published
    property SomeData: string read FSomeData write FSomeData;
  end;
```

To apply the header before sending it, use:

```
  (Webservice as ISOAPHeaders).Send(header);
```

I've created WS-Sec headers (for Username/Password auth) in the past, which I added add GitHub: https://github.com/ronaldhoek/SOAPStuff

[EIDT] Recently added the `BinarySecurityToken` part to the `Security` header for version '200401'.

These could help you build the headers required for this service.

Comment: somedata? wht's that?

Comment: I've updated the WS-Sec 200401 (https://github.com/ronaldhoek/SOAPStuff/blob/master/WSSecurity200401.pas) version to implement the 'BinarySecurityToken'. However, it seems your header has extended the default `Security` implementation with an extra header `<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">`

Comment: The specfications are in http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/ws-securitypolicy-1.2-spec-os.html
Have you an example for usage of your  WSSecurity200401 unit?

Comment: Hmmm, that's completely new - so for now I don't have an implementation. The GitHub project has a Delphi 'Test' project which shows how to use (test) the WS-Sec headers.

Comment: som files not found (  TestsU in 'TestsU.pas',   TestWSSecHeaderU in 'TestWSSecHeaderU.pas')

Comment: @NizamUlMulk sorry, beginner mistake, forgot to add them to the repo. They’re now available.